# Python selenium concurrent multiple page scraper, how to refactor?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, concurrency

I've built a concurrent multiple page scraper using selenium. I've followed the [official docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) and came up with a template for my project which looks like this:

- scraper_a

  - **init**.py
  - data.json (contains links which I am going to scrape)
  - locator.py (just like in the docs)
  - page.py (just like in the docs)
  - scraper.py (instead of test.py shown in 6.1 of the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html))
- scraper_b

  - **init**.py
  - data.json
  - locator.py
  - page.py
  - scraper.py
- scraper_c

  - **init**.py
  - data.json
  - locator.py
  - page.py
  - scraper.py
- driver

  - **init**.py
  - chromedriver.exe
  - driver.py (has a helper function which handles all configuration of the driver)
  - page.py (contains BasePage class)
  - element.py (contains BasePageElement class just like in the docs)
- utils

  - **init**.py
  - io.py (contains helper functions for reading and writing to file)
- main.py (opens up all of the scrapers concurrently)

All of the scrapers have a common task - they go to page A, collect required links from it and save them to data.json, then upon request they load one of the pages and return a number from the page.

All of this is done concurrently using ThreadPoolExecutor.

All of the page.py files follow the same pattern:

```
from utils.io import write_links_to_json
    
    
class SomeElement(BasePageElement):
    locator = SomePagesLocators.SOME_LOCATOR
    
    
class OtherElement(BasePageElement):
    locator = OtherPagesLocators.SOME_LOCATOR
    
class SomePage(BasePage):
    some_element = SomeElement()
    
    def get_links(self):
        # gets required links
        write_links_to_json(links)
            
    
class OtherPage(BasePage):
    other_element = OtherElement()
    
    def get_some_number(self):
        # returns some number
```

Aswell as the scraper.py files:

```
from utils.io import read_links_from_json
from . import page
from driver import set_driver
import atexit


class SomeScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.links = {}
        self.driver = set_driver()
        atexit.register(self.close_driver)

    def setup(self):
        self.driver.get("some link")
        some_page = page.SomePage(self.driver)
        some_page.get_links()

    def get_some_number(self, common_string):
        self.links = read_links_from_json()
        try:
            required_link = next((value for key, value in self.links.items() if common_string in key))
            self.driver.get(link)
            other_page = page.OtherPage(self.driver)
            result = event_page.get_some_number()
            if result is not None:
                return result
            else:
                return "Not found"

    def close_driver(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Here is my main.py

```
from scraper_a.scraper import SomeScraper
from scraper_b.scraper import SomeScraper2
from scraper_c.scraper import SomeScraper3
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scrapers = [SomeScraper(),
                         SomeScraper2(),
                         SomeScraper3()]

    def get_some_number(self, team_name):
        futures = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for scraper in self.scrapers:
                futures.append(executor.submit(scraper.get_some_number, common_string))
        result = ""
        for future in futures:
            result += future.result()
        return result

    def refresh(self):
        futures = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for scraper in self.scrapers:
                futures.append(executor.submit(scraper.setup()))
```

There are two things that concern me:

1. If I want to implement a new scraper, f.e., scraper_d, I have to create a new package and all of the required files, then fill them all in which means I am repeating myself because the files will contain the same structure and methods.
2. If I want to implement a new common method for all of the scrapers, I have to create a new method in all of the page.py files, make it work and then create a corresponding method in all scraper.py files and then create a new method in main.py to work with the scrapers.

Is there a better way of doing all of this? I feel like I am repeating myself a lot and it's getting hard to maintain the scraper.

I don't have much experience on refactoring code, but I have bought Martin Fowler's "Refactoring" 2nd Edition 2019, I could use that as reference to refactor this I just need a little bit of guidance on where to look.